# Sound does not work on a Lenovo Ideapad 310

Tags: sound, lenovo

I did a clean install of Ubuntu 18.04, 64bit on lenovo ideapad 310.
Sound did not work.
I followed online assistance,re-boot after every action

```
sudo alsa force-reload - no sound

install pavucontrol - no sound

install pulseaudio - no sound
```

Also tried the following as per another 'solution' (re-boot after every action)

```
update
update-grub
remove --purge alsa-base
remove --purge pulseaudio
install alsa-base
install pulseaudio
alsa force-reload
install --reinstall libasound2
alsa force-reload
```

Still no sound

```
$ aplay -l 
aplay: device_list:270: no soundcards found...
```

I am lost.

Comment: Although some of us may wear glasses, please don't put the title in upper case. We can read lower case.

Comment: Noted, however, do you have some value to add to the problem?

Comment: Thanks!  ...and unfortunately no, I don't own a Lenovo laptop.

Answer (score 0):

After some more extensive reading I found a post indicating that upgrading the kernel in Ubuntu 14.04 worked.

Did the same with Ubuntu 18.04.1LTS, from 4.15.0-29.31 to 4.17.0 and the sound was properly installed and working well.